# Extension of Notice Period

Tags: employment

My HR has sent an email to everyone in the office stating that the Notice period of all the employees has been extended from 30 days to 90 days. 
Is this legal?
As the Contract that i entered with the company has a specific clause which stated that 30 days notice would be served.

Though in the different Clause at the end of the agreement it is mentioned that that i would be obliged to obey the rules and regulations amended from time to time.

Thus this clause forces me to serve a 90 days notice? 
Whether the email communication send by HR is a deemed acceptance?

Comment: Please be aware that your question is treading the line between on- and off-topic. While questions about terminating employment (and specifically notice periods) are on-topic as shown in the [help/on-topic], [questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694) have been decided to be off-topic.

Comment: Could you tag your location?

Comment: Ask an employment lawyer who specialises in your country/state employment law, do not take legal advice form random people on the internet.

Comment: Welcome to the site Srishti. I noticed that you added a request for help to your post but I'm afraid that we can't really give you an answer that will be helpful to you. We can only recommend that you ask for input from a lawyer or try to evaluate your specific contract yourself using any online resources that might be available for your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

The contract you have between you and your employer, assuming it is a valid one, usually trumps other things, such as vocally-communicated policy changes. Even written changes can be "over-ruled" by your contract, as long as they are coming from personnel who aren't in a position to make them. (By this I mean that if you are in a section of a branch of a division, and your first line supervisor says that your notice period has changed, it is unlikely he has the authority to 'speak for the company' as it were.)

As it happens, however, your contract, according to you, also contains the clause that you are "obliged to obey the rules and regulations (as) amended from time to time."

A large company will set policies and guidance and have those written changes communicated to its employees by HR, just as yours has done. Assuming those changes that HR has emailed everyone about have actually been incorporated into things like the company regulations and/or employee's handbooks, then you have been officially notified of the "amendments" to the notice period, and are now obliged to follow them.

This is my belief as a employee of large and small companies for over 30 years. I am not a lawyer and if you think you have need to "fight" this change, I would highly recommend you seek out professional legal assistance, which is the only way you will really be sure.